# Data Type mismatch in some cases and not others

Tags: sql, ms-access, types, where-clause, criteria

I am building a form in MS Access, and want to add a text field with a simple
`DSum()` function based on a query in my database. The error I keep on getting is

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

However when troubleshooting the issue, I can't find what's mismatching. The field seems ok in a SELECT statement but invalid in a WHERE statement, per the below:

- Original text box formula: `Format(DSum("PValue","N_qryPLBreakdown","Stage Not Like ""*Lost*"""),"£#,##0;;£ -")`
- A query that returns the same error:

```
SELECT SUM(N.PValue) AS SUMVAL
FROM N_qryPLBreakdown AS N
WHERE NOT N.Stage LIKE "*Lost*"
```

- But this query *doesn't* give any errors:

```
SELECT SUM(N.PValue) AS SUMVAL, N.Stage LIKE "*Lost*" AS MismatchField
FROM N_qryPLBreakdown AS N
GROUP BY N.Stage LIKE "*Lost*"
```

I also tried a `SELECT INTO` to put the results of the query `N_qryPLBreakdown` into a table, and looked at the datatype. The offending 'Stage' field was a normal short text field of size 255, and all of the above queries/functions worked on that. However the query I'm running from is very dynamic and I don't want to keep putting the results into a table.

Please help me identify the problem here? What is the query doing that it will throw an error in a WHERE statement but no error for the same thing in a GROUP BY?

Comment: I haven't ever seen a `like` expression in `SELECT` or `GROUP BY` statement. If I had to bet, I would have said the second one is the one wich doesn't work . Are you sure that all your `N.PValue` are numbers?

Comment: @James it was a first for me too I'll admit! Yes, all `N.PValue` are definitely numeric, they will sum fine without the criteria.

Answer (score 2):

The `NOT` is in the wrong place:

```sql
WHERE N.Stage NOT LIKE "*Lost*"
```

If only one 'Lost' option, try with:

```sql
WHERE N.Stage <> 'Closed - Lost'
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I've just tried it and It hasn't fixed the issue (if it was, the original DSUM would have worked)

Comment: What values does `Stage` hold?

Comment: When I inserted into a table, it was Short Text type. The actual field from the query 'N_qryPLBreakdown` is as follows; `Switch(P.Stage_sequence Not Between 1 And 4,Trim(Left(P.stage,InStr(P.stage,'-')+5)),1=1,P.stage_sequence & ' ' & Left(P.stage,IIf(InStr(P.stage,' ')=0,Len(P.stage),InStr(P.stage,' ')-1))) AS Stage` where `P` is a pass-through query from a PostgreSQL database

Comment: Do you think it could be some issue with a PostgreSQL datatype that's pulled through both queries? I'm quite new to Postgres, only worked in T-SQL and MS access SQL to date

Comment: Perhaps. But also the `Switch` expression. What is (sample) output for `Stage`?

Comment: Sample outputs for stage, copied straight from the query; `Closed - Lost`, `1 Lead`, `2 Prospect`, `3 Commitment`, `4 Order`, `Closed - Won`

Comment: Perhaps the query gets confused by the numbers. That won't happen when you Group By, as `Closed - Lost` will be grouped first.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but it's still throwing the same error. For now I'm going to try basing the DSUM on a different query as a workaround (it will just be a more complicated DSUM) but I'll be interested to see if we get any further with this strange bug.

Comment: That's an interesting comment, I'll try adding a zero before it - the numbers were put in to help with sorting. EDIT: still didn't work, sorry!

Comment: Try moving the sort numbers to a separate field and then sort on that.